# How do I clean format an SSD when it is the only hard drive from which I can boot?

Tags: ssd, wipe

I have an SSD I want to wipe and reset (I'm giving it to my little brother). Most SSDs come with [software that can do a secure erase](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?79667-OCZ-Windows-Toolbox-for-Vertex2-3-Agility2-3-and-Solid3-SSD-s), but they are unable to operate when you are booted from the drive you want to erase.

Is there some way I can boot to something like USB drive and perform the wipe from there?

(Oh, and this laptop doesn't have an optical drive)

Comment: Do you really have to do a secure erase?  Is there anything that important on there you can't trust him with?  A simple format would be sufficient otherwise, which can be done at the time that he's installing whatever-he-intends-to-put-on-it.

Comment: @Shinrai: A secure erase wipes all LBAs and sets them to "erased, clean" state on the SSD, restoring the performance the drive had when it was new. A format doesn't do that.

Comment: What specifically is the drive?  Most drives should be taking care of performance degredation as you use them anyway through TRIM or passive garbage collection or similar.

Comment: @Shinrai: Not true. TRIM prevents the pathological cases but it will not restore "like new" performance on most drives. Particularly not on any drives with Sandforce controllers.

Comment: Nope, not on Sandforce, you're right.  That's why I asked what the drive was.  (It'll be hard to say in what kind of bootable environment you can do this in anyway without knowing specifically what drive it is since you'll probably have to use a manufacturer's specific utility!)

Comment: @Shinrai: The secure erase command is an ATA standard. You don't need a manufacturer specific anything to use it.

Comment: Not all controllers meet standards perfectly, and some have their own special secure erase utilities.  From the sounds of it this is a last gen Sandforce drive of some sort, and to my knowledge all of those should support the native ATA secure erase.  That said, you're obviously knowledgable enough that I don't see why you didn't include this kind of detail in the question initially - this is why I seek clarification. :)

Comment: @Shinrai: I don't mess with that in my question because the average user should not need to care about that information.

Comment: I can see where you'd get that impression, but it's generally easier to answer questions correctly and accurately with these sorts of details.  (I don't mean to imply anything personal, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can boot Windows PE from a USB drive.  If your secure erase utility is on that drive, I'd bet it would work.

[This](http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=87312.0) should lead you to the proper information on how to make a Windows PE disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a secure erase utility, such as [HDD Erase](http://www.markc.me.uk/MarkC/Blog/Entries/2009/8/13_Erasing_an_SSD.html) or [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/), from a boot disc (or USB drive).

Comment: This is the recommended way to handle this on any Sandforce-based controller, which apparently OP has. +1

Comment: HDDErase needs an optical drive to work, and doesn't even work on most recent computers. (It's a DOS image and fails on almost all recent hardware -- particularly, every machine I've ever tried to use it, because the DOS image does not support AHCI). DBAN does not issue the secure erase command, it writes random data to the disk (which would make performance worse rather than better).

Comment: HDDErase will work from USB.  I thought it worked in AHCI but I might be remembering wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Its 2018, and this thread still does not have quick and free solution for erasing SSD's when you have no other drive to boot with. **DBAN** is now a commercial product. **[Active KillDisk](http://www.lsoft.net/killdisk.aspx)** makes a great free product for this task. It comes with a bootable usb drive creator. The free version only allows writing one pass of zero's to the drive, but that should be sufficient for the average user.

Comment: DBAN does not engage the SECURITY_ERASE feature of the drive though; that is necessary to completely remove data from wear leveling, etc. usually implemented by destroying a drive-local encryption key. KillDisk is probably sufficient for magnetic media but I wouldn't touch it for SSDs.